# Enabling Flight Recorder in Tomcat causes "Error when initializing JFR"

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, catalina, java-mission-control

adding `-XX:+FlightRecorder` to my CATALINA_OPTS causes this error in my catalina.out log:

```
Error when initializing JFR. JFR will be deactivated.

java.lang.Exception: Unable to create JFR repository directory using base location (/var/cache/tomcat6/temp).
        at oracle.jrockit.jfr.Repository.create(Repository.java:62)
        at oracle.jrockit.jfr.Repository.<init>(Repository.java:26)
        at oracle.jrockit.jfr.JFRImpl.<init>(JFRImpl.java:108)
        at oracle.jrockit.jfr.VMJFR.<init>(VMJFR.java:55)
        at oracle.jrockit.jfr.VMJFR.create(VMJFR.java:393)
        at oracle.jrockit.jfr.JFR.init(JFR.java:91)
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Failed to start tracing backend.
```

Here are the full CATALINA_OPTS from `/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/setenv.sh`:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true \
              -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090 \
              -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
              -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
              -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.202.210.173 \
              -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder"
```

If I only enable the `-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures` parameter the tomcat instance does not crash, as soon as I enable FlightRecorder though, it crashes. I've tried it with JAVA_OPTS also and I get the same result.

I am just following tutorials on the internet to get Flight Recorder enabled for Tomcat, so I don't really have an idea of what I can be doing wrong. Everything looks right to me.

This is on a 64 bit CentOS 6.4 box, with Tomcat 8.

Comment: Even though i didn't have the problem u described above. i was looking for how to enable JFR for tomcat. Thanks for ur explanation i was able to enable JFR by copying your `setenv.sh` file. Just change the hostname to localhost for my configuration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flight Recorder tries to create a repository directory to store temporary data while recording.

The base directory is the directory that the system property *java.io.tmpdir* points to. For some reason the Java process can't access or create a directory there.  Perhaps the Java process doesn't have privileges?

Comment: In that case, setting -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=repository=<path where you have write privileges> might help I guess.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Tomcat didn't have root priveledges. Thank you!